# How to use testNG @Parameters in @BeforeSuite to read value from testng.xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using testNG with Selenium webdriver 3.4. I want to perform the test on for different browser at the same time.

In my testNG.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Demo">
  <test name="Demo on Chrome">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
    <classes>
      <class name="catalogueMemberPortal.CatalogueTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Demo on Firefox">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
    <classes>
      <class name="catalogueMemberPortal.CatalogueTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

My Code

```
public class BaseClass {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
     @BeforeSuite
     @Parameters({"browser"})
     public void launchBrowser(String browser) throws Exception {

         if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")){

             String ffDriverPath = ((System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/browser_drivers/firefox/geckodriver.exe")) ;
             System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",ffDriverPath);
             driver = new FirefoxDriver();
             logger.info("Firefox Initialized");
     }
        // same goes for other type of browsers

     @AfterSuite

     public void afterSuite() {

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

     }
    }
```

Error I am getting

> org.testng.TestNGException: 
>      Parameter 'browser' is required by BeforeSuite on method launchBrowser but has not been marked @Optional or defined
>      in C:\testng.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your browser parameter is located into the `<test>` node, not in the `<suite>` node.
At the suite level, the parameter doesn't exist.

Just replace `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` by `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest`.

Comment: Thank you changing it to @BeforeClass worked for me.

Comment: Yes, it works too because a class is included in a `<test>`.